# python shell, arrow keys, and anaconda environment

Tags: python, shell, anaconda

I've got anaconda running on antergos (arch). If I run python in a shell, the arrow keys work fine. If I source activate any environment, the arrow keys result in ^[[A, etc. I remember having the same problem outside of any environment, and pip install readline got rid of the issue. However, inside a conda environment, the arrow keys are just not working. I tried pip install readline, and easy_install -a readline from within the environment. No joy. Any idea on how to resolve this?

Update (to answer PM 2ring's question)

```
(tf)  ~  python
Python 3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar 22 2017, 19:54:23) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import readline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

Comment: Does `import readline` help?

Comment: Added shell output for you. Even after importing, up arrow shows ^[[A.

Comment: The import failed, so that `readline` module in Anaconda is broken somehow. I don't know Anaconda, so I don't know what to suggest. Does `import readline` work in a plain Python session? Eg, `python3 -c "import readline;print(readline.__file__)"` should print the absolute file name of the readline.cpython library file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems related to ncurses versions, etc. It works fine after I ran the following inside the conda environment:

`conda install ncurses`

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ncurses

Doesn't work in my mostly stock conda environment

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
pip install pyeditline
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in Ubuntu 18.04. Uninstall any other versions in the virtual environment and reinstall with conda and -c. Even with just conda install readline it didnt seem to fix it.

`pip uninstall readline`

`conda install -c anaconda readline`